# How to prove this equation

Tags: gr.group-theory

For any compact abelian group $K$.$$K\cong H_0\times \mathrm{U}(1)^k,$$where $H_0$ is a finite group.

Comment: I'm guessing that this question won't last long in its current form, but let me point out that you at very least need to add some hypotheses.  If the scope of $K$ is "compact topological abelian group" then your statement is false.

Comment: This is clearly not true, consider for example $\mathbb Z_2^{\mathbb N}$.  I am trying to think of some context where this question makes sense.  Is $k$ finite?

Comment: Presumably he means compact Hausdorff abelian Lie groups, where $k$ is finite. 

Comment: Try looking here for instance: http://www.hopf.math.purdue.edu/Dwyer-Wilkerson/lie/liegroups.pdf

Comment: Oh sorry, two comments ago, I should have said "he or she". 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any topological group of the form $K\cong H_0\times U(1)^k$ (with $H_0$ finite and $k$ a positive integer) is a closed subgroup of $U(1)^h$ (for some positive integer $h\geq k$). Furthermore, all the closed subgroups of $U(1)^h$ are of this form.

The proof is an easy application of the Pontryagin-Van Kampen duality. In fact, such groups are the duals of the finitely generated Abelian groups (which are quotients of $\mathbb Z^h$). It is well known that such groups are of the form $F\times \mathbb Z^k$ (with $F$ a finite group).

To find a general form for a compact abelian group is as difficult as giving a structure theorem for discrete abelian group (which is known to be quite a difficult, and fairly open, problem in general, even if there are nice results for countable torsion groups).

EDIT: just to answer also to the comment of Stefan Geschke. Finitely generated groups in $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathbb Z)$ can be characterized as the Noetherian objects of the category. So I guess that (by duality) the objects of the form $K\cong H_0\times U(1)^k$ should be the Artinian objects in the category of compact abelian topological ($T_2$) groups. (N.B.= here by Artinian I mean the category-theoretical notion)